# Was QgsMapLayerRegistry being removed in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is `QgsMapLayerRegistry` going to be availabe in PyQGIS with QGIS 3?

When I typed it into the QGIS python console (2.99), python seems to recognize it because it auto-completes `qgis.core.QgsMapLayerRegistry`, but then gives an error that it's not there:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'qgis.core' has no attribute 'QgsMapLayerRegistry'
```

I tried this with two versions of QGIS 2.99 (one in 01/07 and on in 06/17). Both versions give the same error. `import` doesn't work either:

```
>>>from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry'
```

Is `QgsMapLayerRegistry` removed in QGIS3?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes it has been removed, but alternatives exist.

Changes of the 3.0 API are listed here:

https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

> `QgsMapLayerRegistry`: **Its functionality has been moved to `QgsProject`.**

The main reason is, that QgsMapLayerRegistry is/was a singleton and therefore only a single registry could ever exist. With this constraint removed, major roadblocks are out of the way to implement new things like having multiple projects open side-by-side.

Comment: i think the answer is still incomplete.

Comment: I think you need to give more information why you think the answer is still incomplete.

Comment: if you use QgsProject.instance() how does that solve the singleton issue?

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein you are right, if you use QgsProject.instance() it's not solved. However, standalone apps can already now be implemented with multiple projects and the QGIS server code is moved in this direction too. In the long run QgsProject.instance() *might* completely disappear.

Comment: i dont understand how moving from using a singleton on one part to a singleton on another part changes the ability to run multiple instances (that anyway recieve the same singleton instance (by definition)... wouldn't it make more sense to have a singleton app that gets running instances ? this would also allow much easier interopability and extensibilty (kind of like microsoft office sdk where you can connect to an existing open instance of office or open a new instance

Comment: It's already now possible to work with multiple QgsProject instances side by side. So it is not a singleton by definition, since the constructor is not private. There are still some parts of the internals that use the method `QgsProject.instance()`. These calls need to be reworked in order to be able to continue the work on an API like you propose.

Answer (score 25):

You can do the same thing easily just do:

```
 QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(your_Qgs_whaterver_Layer)
```

for more details, see the following:

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a322fce15a4dd7505398ef9d24295f0c1

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It has saved me while migrating some PyQGIS scripts from QGIS2 to QGIS3