# Creating mid point from line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, point-creation, midpoint

In QGIS I am trying to create a new point layer based on the mid point of a line layer (and keep all the feature attributes in the table).

For example, one line feature becomes one point, located on the mid/center point of the line. Points to lines only seems to work on nodes, and Create points along lines only seems to work at fixed distances?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

If python is Ok for you, you can easily do that with that code snippet.
Copy/paste this code in the editor of the python console, select your line layer and run the script!

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

temp = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:2154", "result", "memory")
temp.startEditing()

attrs = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
temp_prov = temp.dataProvider()
temp_prov.addAttributes(attrs)
temp.updateFields()

for elem in layer.getFeatures():
    feat = QgsFeature()
    geom = elem.geometry().interpolate(elem.geometry().length()/2)
    feat.setGeometry(geom)
    feat.setAttributes(elem.attributes())
    temp.addFeatures([feat])
    temp.updateExtents()

temp.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(temp)
```

This code also take care about keeping the attributes of the line Layer.
Here is my result on a set of line :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to note that the last line doesn't work in QGIS 3, the following works instead:

`QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp)`

[Credit to Abhijit Gujar.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287529/98170)

Comment: @TeddyTedTed You are right, thanks for pointing this!

Comment: Does this save the data of generated nodes in saved layer? I cant see any data

Answer (score 6):

You can use the GDAL/OGR tool: **Create points along lines**.

Make sure you specify `0.5` as the distance. This calculates the **fraction** of the total length (not the distance) as the tool incorporates the [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) function.

---

Here is the default settings shown for me using QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit:

[image: Default settings]

The attributes are also carried over to the output point layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use MMQGIS plugin that will allow you to find the mid point of the layer.

This provide a great resource to learn more about the plugin and the features. You would need to add the plugin via the repository in QGIS [Describes use of MMQGIS, a set of Python vector map layer plugins for Quantum GIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/)

Answer (score 0):

I use a two steps solution:

-First I make count densification with a count equals to one, this adds a mid point to every segment.
   -Then I extract specific nodes, indicating node number 1.

I use this solution because I keep not only the mid point, also the angle of the segment comes as an attribute.
I have a model with the two steps inside, I only have to insert the lines layer