# Getting Bonn 3.2.2 registry error?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-3

This is the error I am getting in QGIS Bonn 3.2.2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined
```

This is the script i am trying to:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():   
    if layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBPolygon:
        with edit(layer):
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Node_ID", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Node_Type", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QR_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QR_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Meridian", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Disc_Mon", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Dis_Lat", QVariant.Double) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Dis_Long", QVariant.Double) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Dis_Dist", QVariant.Int) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Dis_Azi", QVariant.Int) ] )
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: (take a minute and check out how to format code - e.g. `{}` button above the text window. I edited it.)

Comment: `QgsMapLayerRegistry` (among others) has been replaced with `QgsProject`, see e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244452/is-qgsmaplayerregistry-removed-in-qgis3) post. the API changes are quite massive...make sure you check the linked changelog.

Comment: so not sure what I need to do to make this work in the new environment?