# Migration plugin from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3: list layers

Tags: layers, qgis-3, migration

I am trying to migrate a plugin from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3. This function doesn't work with QGIS 3 :

```py
def getLayersByKeyWord(keyword):
    #retourne une liste de layer
    res=[]
    layerMap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    for name, layer in layerMap.iteritems():
        if layer.keywordList() == keyword:
            res.append(layer)
    if len(res)>0:
        return res
    else:
        return None
```

I tried to replace `QgsMapLayerRegistry` with `QgsProject` but it is still not working on `iteritems()`.

---

I still have this error :
for name, layer in layerMap.items:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change two lines. The first one is about PyQGIS 3, the other is about Python 3.

1. Change `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()` into `QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()`. Please check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/244467/29431) out for more information.
2. Change `layerMap.iteritems()` into `layerMap.items()`. Please check [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10458437/5569709) and answers for additional information.