# Adapting variable difference buffer script from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, pyqgis-3

I have a script below which creates variable buffers based on a field `"ALT"` and the coordinates of many points `"X"` and `"Y"`), and dissolves the results. It was written in QGIS 2.X, however I need to migrate this to run using QGIS 3.X.

`QgsGeometryAnalyzer` is retired as of QGIS 3.X, what 3.X PyQGIS class is the replacement class for `QgsGeometryAnalyzer`?

```py
##VariableBuffer=name
##Input_Folder=folder
##Coordinate_Reference_System=crs
##Output_shapefile=output vector

import sys, os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer
import processing
from osgeo import ogr

txt = Input_Folder
TXTlist = []
BuffList = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(txt):
    for name in files:
        nametext = os.path.join(path, name)
        if nametext.lower() [-3:] == "txt":
            TXTlist.append(nametext)

Outdir = txt + "\\shp\\"

if not os.path.exists(Outdir):
    os.makedirs(Outdir)

for txt in TXTlist:
    txtname = os.path.basename(txt)[:-4]
    Outputshp = Outdir + txtname + ".shp"
    Buffer = Outdir + txtname + "_Buffer.shp"
    BuffList.append(Buffer)  
    uri = "file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (txt, Coordinate_Reference_System,"\t", "X","Y")
    layer1  = QgsVectorLayer(uri, txtname, "delimitedtext")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)
    processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', layer1, 'Radius', 0, 10.0, 6.0, True, '"ALT"', Outputshp)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer1)
    processing.runalg("qgis:variabledistancebuffer", Outputshp, 'Radius', 10.0, True, Buffer)

OutputMerge = Outdir + "Merged.shp"
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", BuffList, OutputMerge)
processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", OutputMerge, True, '', Output_shapefile)

del TXTlist, BuffList, txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to get it to work are

Change `QgsMapLayerRegistry` to `QgsProject` according to [this reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244452/is-qgsmaplayerregistry-removed-in-qgis3)  and define `Output_shapefile` to absolute filepath (e.g. " C:/temp.shp") and `Coordinate_Reference_System` to your benifits (e.g. "EPSG:2193") on top of your code.